# c# Conditional object declaration

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I want to declare an object based on a variable value.

This is the code that I'm trying to run and that doesn't compiles:

```
if (bcheck == 0)
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
else if (bcheck == 1)
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
else if (bcheck == 2)
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

If I try to compile the code, I get this error message:

**Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement**

How can I rewrite the code?

The driver object is used in the code below and I have to keep that name in order to don't change program flow.

Comment: Declare `driver` beforehand (with no value) and assign to it in each conditional.

Comment: I'd use a `Dictionary`, Similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505360/2946329

Comment: Ironically none of the answers explain the actual error being given, which is a lack of curly braces.

Comment: The `if`-statement is a  block construct which defines a scope, a scope of a variable determines its visibility to the rest of a program.  So if you don't declare the variable before the `if`-statement, you cannot access it outside. The error message itself is misleading because it tells you that you should use `{}` inside the `if` instead of the embedded statement(one liner) if you want to use a declaration. But if you would do that you still wouldn't be able to access the variable outside of the `if` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `if / else`, a dictionary is much simpler and more extensible.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, IWebDriver>
{
    [0] = new ChromeDriver(),
    [1] = new FirefoxDriver(),
    [2] = new InternetExplorerDriver()
};

var driver = dictionary[bcheck];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IWebDriver driver = null;
if (bcheck == 0)
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
else if (bcheck == 1)
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
else if (bcheck == 2)
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Declare `IWebDriver` outside the `if` condition and assignment inside the `if` condition.

Comment: I generally don't initialize with `null`, since you might not find edge cases where the variable doesn't get set.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare a single variable :

```
IWebDriver driver = null;
if (bcheck == 0)
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
else if (bcheck == 1)
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
else if (bcheck == 2)
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: I generally don't initialize with `null`, since you might not find edge cases where the variable doesn't get set.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `driver` before the if-else statement, but only iniitalize it inside the relevant condition:

```
IWebDriver driver = null;
if (bcheck == 0)
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
else if (bcheck == 1)
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
else if (bcheck == 2)
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: I generally don't initialize with `null`, since you might not find edge cases where the variable doesn't get set.