# How to rewrite switch-statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is there a syntactic sugar or more elegant way to refactor the following code:

```
foreach (var recipient in subscription.Recipients)
{
    switch (recipient.ReceivingMethod)
    {
        case ReceivingMethod.To:
            mail.To.Add(recipient.EMailAdress);
            break;
        case ReceivingMethod.Copy:
            mail.Copy.Add(recipient.EMailAdress);
            break;
        case ReceivingMethod.BlindCopy:
            mail.BlindCopy.Add(recipient.EMailAdress);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use a `Dictionary` usually https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505360/2946329

Comment: If `mail.To` is simple list, you can do `mail.To.AddRange(subscription.Recipients.Where(c => c.ReceivingMethod == ReceivingMethod.To))`, if you like it more that switch.

Comment: I think that is about as readable and elegant as its going to get

Comment: I'd also go for a Dictionary !

Comment: I think with your current code you have a good readability and that, in my opinion, is more important than elegance.

Comment: `recipient.EMailAdress` can be stored in a variable not to repeat 3 times.

Comment: Can you give an example of using a dictionary to access the field please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**423 characters**

```
foreach (var recipient in subscription.Recipients)
{
    switch (recipient.ReceivingMethod)
    {
        case ReceivingMethod.To:
            mail.To.Add(recipient.EMailAdress);
            break;
        case ReceivingMethod.Copy:
            mail.Copy.Add(recipient.EMailAdress);
            break;
        case ReceivingMethod.BlindCopy:
            mail.BlindCopy.Add(recipient.EMailAdress);
            break;
    }
}
```

**311 characters**

```
mail.To.AddRange(subscription.Recipients.Where(c => c.ReceivingMethod == ReceivingMethod.To))
mail.Copy.AddRange(subscription.Recipients.Where(c => c.ReceivingMethod == ReceivingMethod.Copy))
mail.BlindCopy.AddRange(subscription.Recipients.Where(c => c.ReceivingMethod == ReceivingMethod.BlindCopy))
```

Either way. Though i personally think the *former* is the more readable for me

Though if you have printable character OCD, maybe the *later*

***Note*** : I'm not sure a `Dictionary` brings much to the table though

---

**Update from Comments**

> **Zohar Peled** : That's also assuming `mail.To`, `mail.Copy` and `mail.BlindCopy` supports
>   `AddRange` - I'm not sure that assumption is correct, since
>   `System.Net.MailMessage` use the `MailAddressCollection` classes for To,
>   CC and BCC, and that class does not support `AddRange`

and

> **GolezTrol** : Also note that the second option is not just syntactical sugar.
>   Internally you loop through the recipients 3 times, and each results
>   in an enumerable that is passed to `AddRange`, instead of one by one to
>   Add. If `AddRange` is supported, the end result should be the same,
>   though, so it's typically not something to worry about

Comment: That's also assuming `mail.To`, `mail.Copy` and `mail.BlindCopy` supports `AddRange` - I'm not sure that assumption is correct, since `System.Net.MailMessage` use the `MailAddressCollection` classes for `To`, `CC` and `BCC`, and that class does not support `AddRange`.

Comment: 1) it's harder to read 2) you're executing the code all the time!

Comment: *"Though if you have printable character OCD, maybe the later"* - Or find a different language to work in. :-) I agree completely that the switch statement is easier to read. Also note that the second option is not just syntactical sugar. Internally you loop through the recipients 3 times, and each results in an enumerable that is passed to `AddRange`, instead of one by one to `Add`. If `AddRange` is supported, the end result should be the same, though, so it's typically not something to worry about.

Comment: Also No more vote downs! i have a multiple of 5 again for my rep! my OCD has finally gone, or if you do make sure you get 5 of your friends to do it as well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions