# How to redirect to another action inside a function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm testing a condition with a session object and if it's false, I need to redirect somewhere. I'd like to make a function out of it. Normally I would have :

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if (Session["level"] == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Whatever");

    if ((int)Session["level"] == 1)
        return RedirectToAction("Choose", "Whatever");

    // The rest of the code
}
```

But I began have a lot of these in every action... I feel like this is somehow wrong and I would like to put them all in a function so I can focus on `the rest of the code`.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    MaybeRedirect();

    // The rest of the code
}

public void MaybeRedirect()
{
    if (Session["level"] == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Whatever");

    if ((int)Session["level"] == 1)
        return RedirectToAction("Choose", "Whatever");
}
```

When `RedirectToAction` is not returned by an `ActionResult` fonction... it doesn't do anything, of course.

Comment: Change `void` to `ActionResult`. Have `SomeAction` check whether the result is `null` and if it isn't, return it. `var bob = MaybeRedirect(); if (bob != null) return bob;`

Comment: And as an alternative and to get rid of this if-else series, you could use a `Dictionary` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505360/2946329

Comment: @S.Akbari interesting... but i can't figure it out with my exemple.

Comment: @mjwills You just opened my eyes with your comment, it runs the function only once and the var contains the potential action result... brilliant. Will you make this an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a pattern like below. *The key thing is returning `null` to indicate "please **don't** redirect".*

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var predefinedRedirect = MaybeRedirect();

    if (predefinedRedirect != null)
        return predefinedRedirect;

    // The rest of the code
}

private ActionResult MaybeRedirect()
{
    if (Session["level"] == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Whatever");

    if ((int)Session["level"] == 1)
        return RedirectToAction("Choose", "Whatever");

    ... // other conditions here

    return null;
}
```